# Why my Interactive Art is not working like it should on mousemove

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made an Interactive Art but instead of scaling each child different pixels it is scaling each child same `px`.

P.S the commented out code

```js
const WIDTH = 512
const HEIGHT = 256

const ROWS = 8
const COLUMNS = 16

const container = document.querySelector('.container')

for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < ROWS; rowIndex++) {
  for (let colIndex = 0; colIndex < COLUMNS; colIndex++) {
    let x = normalize(colIndex, 0, COLUMNS, 0, WIDTH) + 8
    let y = normalize(rowIndex, 0, ROWS, 0, HEIGHT) + 8

    if (document.querySelectorAll('.dot').length != 128) {
      container.appendChild(circle(x, y))
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMoveEvent)

const dots = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.dot'))

function handleMouseMoveEvent(event) {
  const relativeMousePosition = {
    x: event.clientX - container.getBoundingClientRect().left,
    y: event.clientY - container.getBoundingClientRect().top,
  }

  for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < ROWS; rowIndex++) {
    for (let colIndex = 0; colIndex < COLUMNS; colIndex++) {
      let x = normalize(colIndex, 0, COLUMNS, 0, WIDTH) + 8
      let y = normalize(rowIndex, 0, ROWS, 0, HEIGHT) + 8

      const deltaX = Math.abs(x - relativeMousePosition.x)
      const deltaY = Math.abs(y - relativeMousePosition.y)

      const distance = Math.sqrt(deltaX ** 2 + deltaY ** 2)

      let radius = normalize(distance, 0, 100, 2, 1)
      radius = clamp(radius, 0, WIDTH)

      for (let child = 0; child < dots.length; child++) {
        dots[child].style.transform = `scale(${radius})`
      }
    }
  }
}

function circle(x, y, radius = 16) {
  const dot = document.createElement('div')
  dot.className = 'dot'

  dot.style.width = radius + 'px'
  dot.style.height = radius + 'px'
  dot.style.top = y + 'px'
  dot.style.left = x + 'px'

  return dot
}

function clamp(value, min = 0, max = 1) {
  return Math.max(min, Math.min(max, value))
}

function normalize(number, currentScaleMin, currentScaleMax, newScaleMin = 0, newScaleMax = 1) {
  const standardNormalization = (number - currentScaleMin) / (currentScaleMax - currentScaleMin)
  return (newScaleMax - newScaleMin) * standardNormalization + newScaleMin
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: #111;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 512px;
  height: 256px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px aquamarine; /* FOR DEBUGGING */
}

.dot {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: firebrick;
  transition: transform 125ms ease, top 125ms ease, left 125ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

P.S - The animation which I am trying to make is originally created on `canvas` and based on `react`. But I find `canvas` quite **blur**. See this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smkKv29iaZ8) for animation which I am trying to make.

Comment: I can't see anything in either the JS or CSS that would lead to an animation. Please could you describe what animation you want and what you have done to try to get it.

Comment: Bluring issue could be fixed by disabling antialiasing https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingEnabled

Comment: You never remove old elements, you just add new ones

Comment: container.appendChild(dot(x, y, radius)) this lines adds Childs to container, you have to use something  like container.childs[x] = … or something similar

Comment: @antokhio I changed my code like you stated but still not working as I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the way I would do this animation but the code you are showing has some issues by itself.
You should check the `relativeMousePosition` `x` and `y` properties to trigger the animation when the pointer is inside the `.container` `div`.
Moreover, you should empty the content of the `.container` as well.

I'll show you a quick fix but you still need to work on the animation.
It is not really a solution but a way to point you in the right direction.

I would suggest another way to achieve the same result using a `CSS` `transition` just on the `width` and `height` of the circles and use a `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` instead of adding and removing circles from the `DOM`.

Following the quick fix:

```js
// clean up .container innerHTML
container.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
  container.innerHTML = '';
});

function art(event) {
  const relativeMousePosition = {
    x: event.clientX - container.getBoundingClientRect().left,
    y: event.clientY - container.getBoundingClientRect().top,
  }
  let isInsideContainer = relativeMousePosition.x > 0 && relativeMousePosition.x < 512 && relativeMousePosition.y > 0 && relativeMousePosition.y < 256;
// check the mouse position before triggering the animation
  if(isInsideContainer) {
    for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < ROWS; rowIndex++) {
      for (let colIndex = 0; colIndex < COLUMNS; colIndex++) {
        let x = normalize(colIndex, 0, COLUMNS, 0, WIDTH) + 8
        let y = normalize(rowIndex, 0, ROWS, 0, HEIGHT) + 8
  
        const deltaX = Math.abs(x - relativeMousePosition.x)
        const deltaY = Math.abs(y - relativeMousePosition.y)
  
        const distance = Math.sqrt(deltaX ** 2 + deltaY ** 2)
  
        let radius = normalize(distance, 0, 100, 32, 1)
        radius = clamp(radius, 0, WIDTH)
  
        container.appendChild(dot(x, y, radius))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After Kunal's comment, I added a more detailed possible solution.
This is just a solution you may find other ways to achieve the same result, but it can be a good start.

```js
const WIDTH = 512
const HEIGHT = 256

const ROWS = 8
const COLUMNS = 16

const PROXIMITY_THRESHOLD = Number.parseInt(WIDTH / 6, 10);

// A circle object
// represent an element in the DOM
class Circle {
  constructor(position, id) {
    this.position = position;
    this.id = id;
  }

  distanceFrom(xCoordinate, yCoordinate) {
    const deltaX = Math.abs(this.position.x - xCoordinate);
    const deltaY = Math.abs(this.position.y - yCoordinate);

    const distance = Math.sqrt(deltaX ** 2 + deltaY ** 2)
    return distance;
  }

  isInProximity(distance) {
    return distance <= PROXIMITY_THRESHOLD;
  }
}

const createCircleRow = () => {
  return new Array(COLUMNS)
  .fill(null)
  .map(() =>  new Circle());
};

// We create an array of arrays of circles object
const circles = new Array(ROWS).fill(null).map(createCircleRow);
const container = document.querySelector('.container')

for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < ROWS; rowIndex++) {
  for (let colIndex = 0; colIndex < COLUMNS; colIndex++) {
    let x = normalize(colIndex, 0, COLUMNS, 0, WIDTH) + 8
    let y = normalize(rowIndex, 0, ROWS, 0, HEIGHT) + 8

    // Set the position and the id properties for circle object in circles Array
    circles[rowIndex][colIndex].position = {x, y};
    let id = `${rowIndex},${colIndex}`;
    circles[rowIndex][colIndex].id = id;

    if (document.querySelectorAll('.dot').length != 128) {
      let circleElement = circle(x, y)
      // Add an id to the circle Element
      circleElement.setAttribute('id', id);
      container.appendChild(circleElement);
    }
  }
}

function animateByPosition(xPosition, yPosition) {
  circles.forEach((row) => {
    row.forEach((circle) => {
      let circleElement = document.getElementById(circle.id);
      let distance = circle.distanceFrom(xPosition, yPosition);
      if(circle.isInProximity(distance)) {
        circleElement.style.visibility = 'visible';
        let scaleAmount = 2 * (distance/PROXIMITY_THRESHOLD);
        circleElement.style.transform = `scale(${scaleAmount})`;
      } else {
        circleElement.style.transform = null;
        circleElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }
    });
  });
}

function hideCircles() {
  circles.forEach((row) => {
    row.forEach((circle) => {
      let circleElement = document.getElementById(circle.id);
      circleElement.style.transform = null;
      circleElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    });
  });
}
window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMoveEvent);
container.addEventListener('mouseleave', hideCircles);

function handleMouseMoveEvent(event) {
  const relativeMousePosition = {
    x: event.clientX - container.getBoundingClientRect().left,
    y: event.clientY - container.getBoundingClientRect().top,
  }
  let isInsideContainer = relativeMousePosition.x > 0 && relativeMousePosition.x < 512 && relativeMousePosition.y > 0 && relativeMousePosition.y < 256;
  // check the mouse position before triggering the animation
  if(isInsideContainer) {
    animateByPosition(relativeMousePosition.x, relativeMousePosition.y);
  }
}

function circle(x, y, radius = 16) {
  const dot = document.createElement('div')
  dot.className = 'dot'

  dot.style.width = radius + 'px'
  dot.style.height = radius + 'px'
  dot.style.top = y + 'px'
  dot.style.left = x + 'px'

  return dot
}

function normalize(number, currentScaleMin, currentScaleMax, newScaleMin = 0, newScaleMax = 1) {
  const standardNormalization = (number - currentScaleMin) / (currentScaleMax - currentScaleMin)
  return (newScaleMax - newScaleMin) * standardNormalization + newScaleMin
}
```

```css
.dot {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: firebrick;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer take a look maybe now you can solve my problem. THANKS!

Comment: I updated my solution with some detail, it should be close enough to what you are looking for.